# curl multi requests split result array

Tags: php, mysql, curl

Apologies if this is a very basic questions. I am using multi curl to process an array of various URL's. It seems to work fine however, the results are group into a single array. I would like to insert the results back into my database so I think I need to process the results from each URL individually. My code looks like this:

```
$nodes = array($url1, $url2, $url3);
$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
$results[] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$results[] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$results[] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
}
print_r($results);
```

Is my thinking correct or not, if so how can I split the results?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group you results by the value of `$i` just change the last `foreach` with:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
  $results[$i][] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
  $results[$i][] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  $results[$i][] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
}
```

At the end in `$results` you will have all values grouped in a mulch-dimensional array. You can execute another `foreach` to the `$results` and reformat it in a more semantic way(*for example by url*)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works really well. I don't suppose you can help with my final problem. I am trying to add a function to check if a string is present within the result of each URL request. I have it working without using curl multi but cannot get it to work with multi. This function does the simple check

`$text = curl_exec($ch);
$test = strpos($text, $string);`